# Voice Recognition stops listening after a few seconds I want it alive until press stop button

Tags: android, android-studio, text, voice, speech

What I am using right now.

```
recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 100000000);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "com.languageacademy");
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
```

Please suggest a good way.

Answer (score 0):

there is no "good way", you can't force built-in speech module to listening all the time. its intended to take voice imput just after start, when there will be only silence in first seconds it will turn off, this just works like that (probably some security/privacy reasons)

Comment: Hello @snachmsm , 
Do you have any documentation link for that ?

Comment: sadly no, I was working on this topic few years ago, just remember that